# TypeScript unable to recognize filenames by using @ to indicate

Tags: typescript, eslint

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2020",
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "lib": ["ES2020", "DOM", "DOM.Iterable"],
    "module": "ESNext",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./src/*"]
    },
    /* Bundler mode */
    "moduleResolution": "bundler",
    "allowImportingTsExtensions": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",

    /* Linting */
    "strict": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true
  },
  "include": ["src"],
  "references": [{ "path": "./tsconfig.node.json" }]
}
```

`Failed to resolve import "@/app/hooks" from "src/components/reusable/ProductCard.tsx"`

I may want to ask how to modify the settings in TypeScript in order to have the filenames being recognized by using @ to indicate? I am not sure whether eslint settings should have some problems that the filenames could not be recognized correctly